# External display (HDMI-1) is borked - how to reset just the external display?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I have a new Precision 7770 with a connected HP VH240a monitor via HDMI cable.  OS is Ubuntu 22.04.

xrander -q shows this info for the connected external display:

```
HDMI-1-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00 +  50.00    59.94    60.00  
   1680x1050     60.00    59.88  
   1400x1050     60.00  
   1600x900      60.00    60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02    60.00  
   1440x900      59.90
```

However, the display itself is unusable.  It appears black if configured to separate displays in Display Settings, and when it's mirrored, this is what happens:

[image]

```
xrandr -s 0
```

Only reset the built-in laptop display and did not affect the external display at all.

```
xrandr dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Did not seem to do a thing, other than return to a prompt with no information.

I tried installing the nVidia driver, however that too has the same (frustrating) problem of the external monitor not being detected. For now I am back on the open source driver.

This same external display worked beautifully with Ubuntu 20 on an older Precision laptop, so it is known good.

So - how do I completely reset the **External** display?  I'm okay completely resetting both displays if that's what it takes.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to stop using MATE desktop and switch back to Gnome. I simply wanted ability to add more status icons to the top panel, but it's not worth the hassle.

Moving back to Gnome resolved this issue. MATE worked well on Linux Mint but am not a fan of it under Ubuntu 22.04.